# LogBack + Spring + Tomcat context.xml: How to use variable

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logback

For my Web application I use the context.xml of Tomcat to configure different settings on different servers.

```
<Environment name="FILE_STORAGE_ROOT" value="/vrkarriere/" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
```

This is used inside the services like this

```
@Inject private Environment env;
...
String root = env.getProperty("FILE_STORAGE_ROOT");
```

Now I want tu use this property in the logback.xml also.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <prudent>true</prudent>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>${FILE_STORAGE_ROOT}/logs/vr-karriere.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
```

But it's undefined.
How can I reuse this property?